When generating a new excel-file i get an error that excel has repaired the file
I have created a new ASPX-site that is called upon from the client-side to generate an Excel-file with help of library "ClosedXML.Excel" with the data that is being sent in from a JSON-file.
I generate the file and it is created. The problem occurs when i try to open the file for the first time, and i get an error:

Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded

Looking through the Excel-file, everything seems to be in order and the data i want is there, So i don't understand really why this error is occurring when opening the file for the first time. Since everything is looking fine, I've theorized that error maybe occurs with the JSON is sent in got something my code cant handle, but i don't really know so that is why i created this ask.
But when  troubleshooting and looking through threads on here some think it is how the stream is closed or saved and i also tried that without success. this is how my code looks.
 private void GenerateExcel(List<CuttingPlanningReportData> data)
 {
     try
     {
         string sheetName = "Styckatplanering";
         var regexSearch = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) + new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
         var regex = new Regex($"[{Regex.Escape(regexSearch)}]");
         sheetName = regex.Replace(sheetName, "");

         if (sheetName.Length > 14)
         {
             sheetName = sheetName.Substring(0, 14);
         }

         var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
         IXLWorksheet ws = workbook.Worksheets.Add($"Styckatplanering {sheetName}");
         var row = 1;
         var col = 1;

    
         var headers = new List<string>
 {
     "Datum", "DetaljNamn", "Produktnamn", "Tillgängligt", "Beställt TO", "Utfall TO", "Antal per GE", "Antal detalj TO", "Antal Utfal TO"
 };

         foreach (string s in headers)
         {
             ws.Cell(row, col).Value = s;
             col += 1;
         }

         var range = $"A1:{(char)(headers.Count - 1 + 65)}1";
         ws.Range(range).Style.Font.Bold = true;
         ws.Range(range).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.FromTheme(XLThemeColor.Accent1);
         ws.Range(range).Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.White;

         row++;
         foreach (var item in data)
         {
             ws.Cell(row, 1).Value = item.Date ?? string.Empty;
             ws.Cell(row, 2).Value = item.DetailName ?? string.Empty;
             ws.Cell(row, 3).Value = item.Mmitds ?? string.Empty;
             ws.Cell(row, 4).Value = item.PlannedCuttingCount.HasValue ? item.PlannedCuttingCount.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
             ws.Cell(row, 5).Value = item.Vhorqa.HasValue ? item.Vhorqa.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
             ws.Cell(row, 6).Value = item.GE.HasValue ? item.GE.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
             ws.Cell(row, 7).Value = item.Mucofa.HasValue ? item.Mucofa.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
             ws.Cell(row, 8).Value = item.CountSql.HasValue ? item.CountSql.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
             ws.Cell(row, 9).Value = item.CountResult.HasValue ? item.CountResult.Value.ToString() : string.Empty;

             row++;
         }

         ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();

         var fileName = $"Styckatplanering-{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.xlsx";

         using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
         {
             workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
             Session["ExcelFileName"] = fileName;
             Session["ExcelFileContent"] = memoryStream.ToArray();
        
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         // Log the error
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error generating Excel: " + ex.Message);
         throw;
     }
 }

 private void DownloadFile()
 {
     try
     {
         var fileName = Session["ExcelFileName"] as string;
         var fileContent = Session["ExcelFileContent"] as byte[];

         if (fileName != null && fileContent != null)
         {
             Response.Clear();
             Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
             Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName}");
             Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);
             Response.Flush();
             HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
         }
         else
         {
             throw new Exception("File content not found in session.");
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error downloading file: " + ex.Message);
     }
 }

I have tried
  using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
      workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
      Session["ExcelFileName"] = fileName;
      Session["ExcelFileContent"] = memoryStream.ToArray();
      memoryStream.Close();
 
  }

That did not either work, my thought here was if the stream was not closed maybe that is why the corruption occured.
And also tried to add  if (sheetName.Length > 30)  {      sheetName = sheetName.Substring(0, 30);  }
if there was someting wrong with the lenght of the name. but that did not work.
and lastly i tried also
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
       {
           try
           {
 
               var requestBody = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Request Body: " + requestBody);


               var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
               var requestData = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<CuttingPlanningReportData>>>(requestBody);

               if (requestData != null && requestData.TryGetValue("jsonData", out var data))
               {
                   GenerateExcel(data);
                   Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                   Response.Write("{\"success\": true}");
               }
               else
               {
                   throw new Exception("jsonData key not found in the request data or deserialization failed");
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
     
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
               Response.ContentType = "application/json";
               Response.Write("{\"success\": false, \"message\": \"" + ex.Message + "\"}");
           }
           finally
           {
               Response.End();
           }
       }
       else if (Request.QueryString["download"] == "1")
       {
           DownloadFile();
       }
   }

and i also tried to add response contentType and set it to JSON. But it did not help remove the error.
Edit 1 :
Ok i testes now with generating an empty excel file without content, and it still wants to repair the file when opening the file for the first time. So it must be something with how the file is created or saved, i have also saved it direct to the HD instead. like var fileName = $"Styckatplanering-{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.xlsx"; var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);              workbook.SaveAs(filePath);

Please can you try and work out where this is going wrong: is ClosedXML generating an invalid file, or is the file getting corrupted during the download? e.g. is it getting truncated when you're saving it into the Session? I'm not sure Session is intended for large binaries: what storage are you using for the session?

It would be worth trying saving your generated Excel file to disk as well / instead and see if they're valid, or if it's not trying a simpler example e.g. an empty sheet or just a string. You can also run them through a zip tool's test function to see if that adds anything.

Ok i testes now with generating an empty excel file without content, and it still wants to repair the file when opening the file for the first time. So it must be something with how the file is created or saved, i have also saved it direct to the HD instead. like `var fileName = $"Styckatplanering-{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.xlsx";
var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
workbook.SaveAs(filePath);`  @Rup

And saving it directly to the HD gives you a broken file? Then that's a problem with the ClosedXML library. I'd ask them directly about it.

Hello again @Rup i got an update, file that is saved to the App_Data folder works without error, but its the file that when its opened in the download-folder then it shows the error.

OK, then I'd guess it's getting corrupted by being stored and retrieved from Session. I'm not sure why that would be though, perhaps truncation because of size or because of some character it contains. Can you compare the two files to see how they're different?

I solved it and i will update the original post but the downloaded folder version contained html.










 the the one in the app folder didnt have the html. so i fixed the problem by removing all htm in the aspx-file and just leave the <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ExportToexcelReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="code.ExportToexcelReport" %> and now it works! :) thanks! i will update the OP for future reference @Rup
I solved the problem! The reason it was giving my a prompt to repair the file was that it was also sending into the excelfile the html of the ASPX-file so it needed to clean away that each time. so the solution was to remove the html and just keep the line that references the code behind in the aspx-file. and now it worked!
